# What is the best way to show the percentage value of each element against the column total using Python 3 and Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have a 30000000 x 3 matrix of random integers. I want to show the percentage value of each element against the column total using Python 3 and Numpy. Below are four approaches I used.

Is there a better way anyone can suggest please?
I find method 2 is slightly slower than method 1, despite one less For loop. Any idea why?

Method 3 and 4 is best as it seems to use python vectorization.

Times for each method on my laptop: Method 1 takes 12000 millisecs, Method 2 takes 13500 ms, Method 3 takes 240 ms, Method 4 takes 254 ms.

```
#
import numpy as np
import time
#
## make matrix of 10,000 x 3 of random integers
a = (np.random.rand(30000000).reshape(-1,3) * 10).astype(int)
nRows = a.shape[0]
nCols = a.shape[1]
print(f"nRows = {nRows}\tnCols = {nCols}\n\n")
#
## METHOD 1: with two for loops
tic = time.time()
ans = np.zeros(a.shape)
for coli in range(nCols):
    colsum = np.sum(a[:,coli])
    for rowi in range(nRows):
        ans[rowi, coli] = a[rowi, coli] / colsum
ans *= 100
print(f"{ans}")
toc = time.time()
print(f"method 1 = {1000*(toc-tic)} ms\n")
#
## METHOD 2: -- one less for loop
tic = time.time()
ans = np.zeros(a.shape)
colTotals = np.sum(a, axis=0)
for rowi in range(nRows):
    ans[rowi] = a[rowi] / colTotals
ans *= 100
print(f"\n{ans}")
toc = time.time()
print(f"method 2 = {1000*(toc-tic)} ms\n")
#
## METHOD 3: fastest way -- no for loops
tic = time.time()
ans = np.zeros(a.shape)
colTotals = np.sum(a, axis=0)
ans = a / colTotals.reshape(1, nCols)
ans *= 100
print(f"\n{ans}")
toc = time.time()
print(f"method 3 = {1000*(toc-tic)} ms\n")
#
## METHOD 4: fastest way -- no for loops
tic = time.time()
ans = np.zeros(a.shape)
colTotals = np.sum(a, axis=0).reshape(1,-1)
colTotals = np.repeat(colTotals, nRows, axis=0)
ans = a / colTotals
ans *= 100
print(f"{ans}")
toc = time.time()
print(f"method 4 = {1000*(toc-tic)} ms\n")
#
```

Comment: What about `a / a.sum(axis=0)`?

Comment: Sorry Daniel, could could see the question again please. I added a fourth method after you commented.